# How to add rms noise to a signal

Tags: python, simulation, noise, imu

I am working with an IMU sensor [1](https://www.xsens.com/mti-7) that has a noise density of:

[image]

I wish to simulate the noise that this IMU will have in one of the simulations I have ran. From my understanding and using [this video reference](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/756529027001.html), the rms is 5.4mG. I am not sure how to add this noise to the data. I am currently coding in python